# Postgres alter field type from float4 to float8 on huge table

Tags: postgresql, types, alter-table

I want to alter column data type from float4 to float8 on a table with huge rows count. If I do it in usual path it takes much time and my table blocked for this time.
IS any hack to do it without rewrite the table content?

Comment: Describe the _usual path_

Comment: ALTER TABLE ALTER COLUMN ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ALTER TABLE ... ALTER COLUMN ... TYPE ... USING ...` (or related things like `ALTER TABLE ... ADD COLUMN ... DEFAULT ... NOT NULL`) requires a full table rewrite with an exclusive lock.

You can, with a bit of effort, work around this in steps:

- `ALTER TABLE thetable ADD COLUMN thecol_tmp newtype` without `NOT NULL`.
- Create a trigger on the table that, for every write to `thecol`, updates `thecol_tmp` as well, so new rows that're created, and rows that're updated, get a value for `newcol_tmp` as well as `newcol`.
- In batches by ID range, `UPDATE thetable SET thecol_tmp = CAST(thecol AS newtype) WHERE id BETWEEN .. AND ..`
- once all values are populated in `thecol_tmp`, `ALTER TABLE thetable ALTER COLUMN thecol_tmp SET NOT NULL;`.
- Now swap the columns and drop the trigger in a single tx:

  - `BEGIN;`
  - `ALTER TABLE thetable DROP COLUMN thecol;`
  - `ALTER TABLE thetable RENAME COLUMN thecol_tmp TO thecol;`
  - `DROP TRIGGER whatever_trigger_name ON thetable;`
  - `COMMIT;`

Ideally we'd have an `ALTER TABLE ... ALTER COLUMN ... CONCURRENTLY` that did this within PostgreSQL, but nobody's implemented that. Yet.

Comment: my case is more complex :-( my table is parent table with partitions (inherited tables) with data one table per month. So if i change parent table -all inherited tables have to be updated and parent table is locked for this time. Every inherited table have 10-30 Gb

Comment: It would help if you mentioned important details like this in your original question. I don't see a fundamental barrier to using the same approach with inherited tables, though I have not tried it. It'll make adding a `not null` constraint slower, but otherwise I don't think anything there should require long locks.

Comment: Ok. Yours way helps :-)